# Where is the mkmf.log file located on os x mavericks using rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks, rbenv, mkmf

I am running OS X Mavericks and using `rbenv` for managing my ruby versions. For ruby version 1.9.3-p448 for instance, where would the file `mkmf.log` be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `rmagick` version 2.11.1 and ruby version 1.9.3-p448 I located the file here:

`~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.11.1/ext/Rmagick`

The last part of that path `/Rmagick` might not apply to all gems. I think the `mkmf.log` file is located just inside `/ext` at the end of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the whole list of them via:

`find ~/.rbenv -name mkmf.log`

or

`find ~/.rvm -name mkmf.log`